# "undefined" label references in AS assembler

Tags: assembly, x86, linker, osdev, gnu-assembler

I have been trying to use a collection of various resources recently (mostly https://wiki.osdev.org and https://www.osdever.net). And currently I am trying to initialize a GDT in my assembly file **boot.s**:

```
.set ALIGN,    1<<0             /* align loaded modules on page boundaries */
.set MEMINFO,  1<<1             /* provide memory map */
.set FLAGS,    ALIGN | MEMINFO  /* this is the Multiboot 'flag' field */
.set MAGIC,    0x1BADB002       /* 'magic number' lets bootloader find the header */
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS) /* checksum of above, to prove we are multiboot */
 

.section .multiboot
.align 4
.long MAGIC
.long FLAGS
.long CHECKSUM
 
.section .bss
.align 16
stack_bottom:
.skip 16384 # 16 KiB
stack_top:
 


.section .text
.global _start

.type _start, @function
_start:

    mov $stack_top, %esp
 

    # setup GDT
    cli
    xor %ax, %ax
    mov %ds, %ax
    lgdt gdt_desc
    sti


    call kernel_main
 

    cli
1:  hlt
    jmp 1b
 
.size _start, . - _start
```

I am also linking a file titled **gdt.s**

```
.global gdt
.global gdt_null
.global gdt_code
.global gdt_data
.global gdt_end
.global gtd_desc
gdt:

gdt_null:
    .8byte 0

gdt_code:
    .2byte 0xFFFF
    .2byte 0x0000
    .byte 0
    .byte 0b10011010
    .byte 0b11001111
    .byte 0
gdt_data:
    .2byte 0xFFFF
    .2byte 0
    .byte 0
    .byte 0b10010010
    .byte 0b11001111
    .byte 0
gtd_end:

gtd_desc:
    .2byte gdt_end - gdt
    .2byte gdt
```

(I got this by following https://http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/the-world-of-protected-mode)

Then I have a linker script to link the files:

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 1M;
    .text BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.multiboot)
        *(.text)
    }
 
    /* Read-only data. */
    .rodata BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }
 
    /* Read-write data (initialized) */
    .data BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(.data)
    }
 
    /* Read-write data (uninitialized) and stack */
    .bss BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
    }
 
}
```

I compile the assembly files with:
`as --32`

And link them using:
`g++ -m32 -T linker.ld -o myos.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib boot.o kernel.o gdt.o -lgcc`

(note that `kernel.o` is not relevant to the question)

And I get the errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: boot.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `gdt_desc'
/usr/bin/ld: gdt.o: in function `gtd_end':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `gdt_end'
(.text+0x18): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_PC8 against undefined symbol `gdt_end'
(.text+0x19): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.text'
```

Comment: Declare labels as `.global`

Comment: control-F shows that `lgdt gdt_desc` is the only occurrence of that symbol name in any of the code in the question, except the error message.  Unless you define it via a macro that pastes two names together, it should be pretty obvious that nothing defines it at all, let alone exporting it as `.global` so another file could link to it.

Comment: Oh, and searching for `gdt_end`, I found a typoed `gtd_desc`.  Note that the GDT limit is a word, not a byte, in the memory operand for `lgdt`.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lgdt:lidt

Comment: I have changed the GDT limit. I have made the labels global in gdt.s. I still get the same error message.

Comment: Your source still has 3 occurrences of `gtd` instead of `gdt`.  Also, 32-bit mode `lgdt` wants a 6-byte memory operand, with a 2-byte limit and a 4-byte virtual address.  I didn't look at all your code, but I assume you're not intending to use 16-bit protected mode.  So use `.long` aka `.4byte` for the address.